# Constructive proof of compactness theorem for countable propositional languages

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, constructive-mathematics

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a countable propositional language and let $\Gamma$ be a set of propositions of $\mathcal{L}$ (i.e. $\Gamma \subseteq \text{Prop}(\mathcal{L})$).

Definition: $\Gamma$ is satisfiable if there exists an evaluation function $V:\text{Prop}(\mathcal{L}) \to \{\bot,\top\}$ such that $V(C)=\top$ for every $C \in \Gamma$ ($\{\bot,\top\}$ is the 2-elements boolean algebra).

Compactness theorem for countable languages: if every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable then $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.

The compactness theorem for countable languages can be proved in ZF (Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory). Is it provable also in a constructive way (i.e. in CZF or in IZF)?

Otherwise, does the compactness theorem for countable languages imply some intuitionistic taboo?

Answer (score 3):

No, this cannot be constructively proved.

Consider a one-proposition language $\mathcal{L} = \{P\}$. Fix a consider a meta-level proposition $Q$. Define $\Gamma = \{P \mid Q\} \cup \{\neg P \mid \neg Q\}$.

I claim every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable. This is fairly straightforward, since every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is either $\emptyset$, $\{P\}$, or $\{\neg P\}$.

If $\Gamma$ is satisfiable, we examine the truth value $P$ takes in the model. If $P \mapsto \top$, then we know $\neg \neg Q$. And if $P \mapsto \bot$, then we know $\neg Q$. So if $\Gamma$ is satisfiable, then either $\neg Q$ or $\neg \neg Q$ holds.

But we cannot constructively prove $\neg Q \lor \neg \neg Q$.

Conversely, if we assume $\forall Q (\neg Q \lor \neg \neg Q)$, then we can prove the compactness theorem for $\mathcal{L} = \mathbb{N}$. We can define

$$V(i) = \begin{cases}
  \top & \text{there is no finite set } S \subseteq \Gamma \text{ such that there is no satisfier } V’ \text{ of } S \text{ with } \forall j < i, V’(j) = V(j) \text { and } V’(i) = \top \\
  \bot & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

on the atomic propositions (and extend in the obvious way to all propositions).

We can then prove by induction that for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, for all finite subsets $S \subseteq \Gamma$, there exists a truth assignment $V’ \models S$ such that for all $j \leq i$, $V’(j) = V(j)$. It follows that $V \models \Gamma$.

Comment: What is a meta-level proposition? And what does $\{P \mid Q\}$ mean?

Comment: I meant that I am not intending that $Q$ be an element of $\mathcal{L}$. Instead, we should view $Q$ as an ordinary mathematical proposition (such as the continuum hypothesis, Collatz conjecture, prime number theorem, etc.).

Comment: $\{P \mid Q\}$ is the set $\{x \mid (x = P) \land Q\}$.

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is satisfiable we examine the truth value P takes in the model (based on the $\{0,1\}$-algebra). If $P \mapsto \top$ then $\neg P \mapsto \bot$, then $\neg Q$ is not true. But why "$\neg Q$ is not true" implies "$\neg \neg Q$ is true" in a constructive context?

Comment: @effezeta $\neg C$ means “$C$ is not true”. So the meaning of $\neg \neg Q$ is that $\neg Q$ is not true. More formally, to prove $\neg C$, we begin by assuming $C$ and deriving a contradiction. If $P \mapsto \top$ and $\neg Q$, then we have a contradiction. Thus, we have $\neg \neg Q$ in the case that $P \mapsto \top$.

Comment: Is this proof by contradiction considered constructive?

Comment: This is not proof by contradiction. It’s proof of negation. https://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/#:%7E:text=Proof%20of%20negation%20is%20an,the%20same%20classically%20and%20intuitionistically.

Comment: you're right. I have a last question. When we examine the truth value P takes in the model we have only two cases: $P \mapsto \top$ or $P \mapsto \bot$. But when we consider the meta-level proposition $Q$ we can have more than two cases: we can evaluate $Q$ in a general Heyting algebra for example. So if $Q$ is not true I cannot deduce that $\neg Q$ is true, right?

Comment: @effezeta We are not discussing whether $Q$ holds in a model of our meta-theory. Instead, we are reasoning within our meta-theory. It is true that if you use a Heyting-valued model $M$ of, say, IZF, then $\neg (M \models Q)$ does not necessarily mean $M \models \neg Q$. Exactly the same phenomenon occurs in Boolean-valued models of ZFC. But this is irrelevant here.